# How to convert pipe-delimited file to CSV format in bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a gigantic 300MB text file that is a pipe delimited CSV.

```
Some Writing, Is|Another Field|Anotherfie,ld.
Some Writing, Is|Another Field|Anotherfie,ld.
```

Is there a way in bash shell to convert it to:

```
"Some Writing, ","Another Field","Anotherfie,ld."
```

Comment: generally, pipe-delimited data is less fragile. Most software **can** read in pipe-delimited data, sometimes just by naming the file extension as `.csv`. Double-check the possibility of reading in pipe-delimited data. Or are you seeing `|` in your data columns? (Just as you're seeing `,`s in your data). Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/^/"/;s/|/","/g;s/$/"/' file
```

Output:

```
"Some Writing, Is","Another Field","Anotherfie,ld."
"Some Writing, Is","Another Field","Anotherfie,ld."
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" add sed's option `-i`.

Comment: @thistleknot: If `sed` is available to you, it should work everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sed` and it's substitution commands:

`s/^/"/` will replace (insert) a `"` sign at the beginning of each line.
`s/|/","/g` will replace each `|` character with `","` triplet. Note the `g` letter at the end of command, which instructs it to replace *every* `|` occurrence, not only the first one.
And finally:
`s/$/"/` will replace (append) a `"` sign at the end of each line.

So final command will be:

```
`cat filename.in | sed 's/^/"/;s/|/","/g;s/$/"/` > filename.out`
```

Comment: This replaces pipes with periods.

Comment: @bradw2k: Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i="\"" $i "\""} 1' file.csv
"Some Writing, Is","Another Field","Anotherfie,ld."
"Some Writing, Is","Another Field","Anotherfie,ld."
```